# Tomcat failing to launch because of no DefaultSerializerProvider

Tags: tomcat, jackson, dependencies

Im trying to upgrade my jackson dependencys up to version 2.11 across the board but now whenever I try to launch my application I get this error

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1129)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1871)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:749)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/DefaultSerializerProvider
        at com.amazon.spring.platform.runtime.RequestConfiguration.attributionFrameSerializer(RequestConfiguration.java:80)
        at com.amazon.spring.platform.runtime.StandardPlatformWebApplicationInitializer.addFilters(StandardPlatformWebApplicationInitializer.java:512)
        at com.amazon.spring.platform.runtime.StandardPlatformWebApplicationInitializer.onStartup(StandardPlatformWebApplicationInitializer.java:325)
        at com.amazon.horizonte.config.HorizonteWebApplicationInitializer.onStartup(HorizonteWebApplicationInitializer.java:43)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1344)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1172)
        ... 17 more
```

And I can not figure out why or how to fix this issue, I can't really upgrade Apache version and I tried downgrading jackson to the lowest possible I can of 2.10 and that didn't help either.  The previous version it was running on was 2.9.x versions of everything which I can no longer do as its been banned for security reasons in my work. Im not sure what else I can do to try and fix it.

Comment: It doesn't look like a version problem (all versions have that class), but rather like a missing [`jackson-databind.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.11.4). Are you sure this library is deployed with the application?

Comment: It's should be or it wouldn't be able to build properly. One thing I noticed is that after the upgrade I had to change the import names. Do you think it's possible that its using the old import and so that's why it's failing?